# Function of media query "only screen" syntax?

Tags: css

have been wondering about the CSS syntax `only screen`.

Basically:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) { ... }

@media (max-width: 800px) { ... }
```

Other than the first one not appearing when **printed**, is there any other benefit?

What confuse me is Famous framework like [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) choose to slap `only screen` on all of their @media. While others like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries:

*The only keyword prevents older browsers that do not support media queries with media features from applying the given styles:*

And `screen` is for all devices which have screen. So eg. print styles are excluded.

Comment: Does it mean if I'm not planning to support below IE9, I can safely not write `only screen`?

Comment: @DarcCode: IE<=8 doesn't know media queries, it doesn't matter what ou write there :-)